# How to set binded attribute to custom component in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, components

Hello I'm trying to add a custom Vue component to my template using the DOM, I already setted the properties, but I can't set the associated attribute of events in the custom component. Here is my `buttonVue.vue` component (child component) **:**

```
export default {
emits:['action','isAuth'],
data:function(){
    return {msg:this.textDisplay()}
},
 methods:{
    textDisplay(){
        return this.$emit('isAuth')?'Sign in with Microsoft':'Sign out from Microsoft'
    }
 }
}
</script>
```

parent component:

```
 insertBtnComponent){
    var ComponentClass = Vue.extend(buttonVue)
    var instance = new ComponentClass({
    propsData:{class:"buttonMs" ,style:" position: static ;",
    'action':this.isUserAuthenticated()?this.signOut():this.signInUser(),
    'isAuth':this.isUserAuthenticated()
   }
 })
  let selector = document.querySelector(".classNAMEofDiv");
  instance.$mount()
  selector.appendChild(instance.$el)
```

I would appreciate any hints on my problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of using emit events from child. You can pass `isAuth` value from parent to child as a prop and then in child you can show the message. If this can work, I can help you in resolving the issue.

Comment: @Rohìt Jíndal.I think I got you ,thanks.But, what about 'action'?Would be greate if you got some ideas.

Comment: As per my understanding, `action` is to invoke `signIn` or `signOut` method based on the `isAuth` value. So now my question is that those links will be in child component or parent ? If those links are in parent then no need to pass `action` in the child.

Comment: They are in parent component,how ever the child component is similar to button behavior,so that's why I wanted to pass these links to child component.To determinate the event on @click.
Are there some parameters in Vue.extend to determinate the emits?

Comment: I think i need to understand your component design for parent as well as child. So that I will help you. Is there any way we can connect over an mail ? or if you can tell me here that will also fine. What is the role of parent and child ?

Comment: Thank you dude,appreciate your intention to help me,but I resolved it myself.Best regards.

Comment: Nice to hear this. Cheers!